# How to fix IMPORTJSON returning 403 HTTP error code?

Tags: json, google-apps-script, google-sheets, http-status-code-403, urlfetch

I have been trying to import a JSON file from SEC EDGAR but have been unsuccessful. It shows the following error:

> Exception: request failed for https://data.sec.gov returned code 403. Truncated server response:  <html xmlns="http://www.w... (use muteHttpExceptions option to examine full response) (line 220)

The function that I have been using can be found here (with no modifications): https://github.com/bradjasper/ImportJSON

It is working normally for other sites, the only one so far that I had problem is the SEC EDGAR site: https://data.sec.gov/api/xbrl/companyconcept/CIK0000320193/us-gaap/AccountsPayableCurrent.json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is :

> Your Request Originates from an Undeclared Automated Tool. To allow for equitable access to all users, SEC reserves the right to limit requests originating from undeclared automated tools. Your request has been identified as part of a network of automated tools outside of the acceptable policy and will be managed until action is taken to declare your traffic.

```
function getStatusCode(url='https://data.sec.gov/api/xbrl/companyconcept/CIK0000320193/us-gaap/AccountsPayableCurrent.json'){
   var options = {
     'muteHttpExceptions': true,
     'followRedirects': false
   };
   var url_trimmed = url.trim();
   var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url_trimmed, options);
   Logger.log (response.getResponseCode());
   Logger.log (response.getContentText())
}
```

the only way I know is to copy manually the json in a cell then parse it