# Google Sheets / Scripts API Call with User-Agent Results in Code 403

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, http-status-code-403

I want to import JSON data into Google Sheets using the `ImportJSON` function.  [The host requires declaring a "User-Agent"](https://www.sec.gov/os/accessing-edgar-data) with each call:

[image]

Per the [ImportJSON docs](https://github.com/bradjasper/ImportJSON), I've extended the `ImportJSONAdvanced` function with a custom function to pass headers to the host:

```js
/**
@customfunction
**/
function ImportJSON_SEC(url, query, parseOptions) {
  var header = {headers: {'User-Agent': 'My Company my_company@example.com',}}
  return ImportJSONAdvanced(url, header, query, parseOptions, includeXPath_, defaultTransform_)
}
```

I used the following formula in Google Sheets to import the file:

```
=ImportJSON_SEC("https://data.sec.gov/api/xbrl/companyconcept/CIK0000320193/us-gaap/Assets.json","/","noInherit,noTruncate,allHeaders")
```

This results in a 403 error, even though the User-Agent should have been declared:

> Exception: Request failed for https://data.sec.gov returned code 403.

**QUESTIONS:**

**Why am I getting a 403 error?  What am I doing wrong?**

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70061142/3035713) from a similar question doesn't declare the header.